# How to get select list of all object's fields by Id in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

> How to get select list of object's fields by Id in visualforce page

like :
[image]

Thanks in Advance ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [dev forum link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090fnIAA) which describes a similar solution. I have copied the solution here. Hope this will be a good starting point.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="Describer">
  <apex:form id="Describe">
    <apex:pageBlock id="block2" >
      <apex:pageblockbuttons location="top" >
        <apex:commandButton value="Get Describe Object Fields" action="{!showFields}"/>
      </apex:pageblockbuttons>
      <apex:pageblocksection >
        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectNames}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
      </apex:pageblocksection>
      <apex:pageblocksection id="fieldList" rendered="{!not(isnull(selectedObject))}">
        <apex:panelBar items="{!fields}" var="fls">
          <apex:panelBarItem label="{!fls.key}">{!fls.val}</apex:panelBarItem>
        </apex:panelBar>
      </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class Describer {
    public Map < String, Schema.SObjectType > schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    public List < Pair > lstfieldname {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List < Pair > fields {
        get {
            return lstfieldname;
        }
        set {
            lstfieldname = value;
        }
    }
    public List < SelectOption > objectNames {
        public get;
        private set;
    }
    public String selectedObject {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // Intialize objectNames and fields

    public Describer() {
        objectNames = initObjNames();
        fields = new List < Pair > ();
    }
    // Populate SelectOption list -

    // find all sObjects available in the organization

    private List < SelectOption > initObjNames() {
        List < SelectOption > objNames = new List < SelectOption > ();
        List < String > entities = new List < String > (schemaMap.keySet());
        entities.sort();
        for (String name: entities)
        objNames.add(new SelectOption(name, name));
        return objNames;
    }

    // Find the fields for the selected object

    public void showFields() {
        //fields.clear();
        system.debug('$$$$$' + selectedObject);
        Map < String, Schema.SObjectField > fieldMap = schemaMap.get(selectedObject).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        for (Schema.SObjectField sfield: fieldMap.Values()) {
            schema.describefieldresult dfield = sfield.getDescribe();
            system.debug('#######' + dfield);
            Pair field = new Pair();
            field.key = dfield.getname();
            system.debug('#######4444' + field.key);
            field.val = dfield.getType() + ' : ' + dfield.getLabel();
            lstfieldname.add(field);
        }
    }

    public class Pair {
        public String key {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public String val {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but it's not helped so much.